# Javascript library for building a flowchart application

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to realize a web interface with drag and drop where the user needs to create a flowchart by adding blocks as rectangles and polygons connected one to the other in 1:1 and 1:n relationships.
A single object needs to have a text field where the user can add a description and he must be able to connect an object with another by adding a description to the connection.

I'm trying to understand which framework / library i have to use. I've seen [JSPlumb](http://jsplumb.org/jquery/demo.html) that seems good for my job but i've also found [D3](http://d3js.org) that is very very fancy even if it seems to be related to Data instead of UI creation. Could D3 be a good choice for my work?

Comment: http://www.jgraph.com/mxgraph.html / http://thejit.org/ / http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16192/Graphic-JavaScript-Tree-with-Layout one of those should fit your needs!

Comment: Did you went on with the project? What did you end up using?